# numpy unique with customized sorting of unique elements of an array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

Given:

```
R=["ip1", "ip7", "ip12", "ip5", "ip2", "ip22", "ip7", "ip1", "ip17", "ip22"]
```

I would like to get unique values of my list `R` with their corresponding indices.

Right now, I have `name,idx=np.unique(R,return_inverse=True)` which returns:

```
array(['ip1', 'ip12', 'ip17', 'ip2', 'ip22', 'ip5', 'ip7'], dtype='<U4') # name
[0 6 1 5 3 4 6 0 2 4]                                                    # idx
```

But I would like to use customized sorting with results as follows:

```
['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip5', 'ip7', 'ip12', 'ip17', 'ip22']
[0 3 4 2 1 6 3 0 5 6]
```

In `list`, I can use `Rs=sorted(R, key=lambda x: int(x[2:]))` with customized `key` but I can't get unique values and corresponding indices.

Is there any way to manipulate sorting key `np.unique` or is there already a better approach handling this?

Comment: Python `set` should be just as good as `unique`, especially for strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) after conversion to int:

```
_, i, idx = np.unique([int(x[2:]) for x in R],
                      return_index=True,
                      return_inverse=True)

names = np.array(R)[i]
```

output:

```
# names
array(['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip5', 'ip7', 'ip12', 'ip17', 'ip22'], dtype='<U4')

# idx
array([0, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing modification in the code. I got the desired output.

```
import numpy as np

R = ["ip1", "ip7", "ip12", "ip5", "ip2", "ip22", "ip7", "ip1", "ip17", "ip22"]
unique_values, indices = np.unique(R, return_inverse=True)
def custom_sort_key(value):
    return int(value[2:])


sorted_indices = np.argsort([custom_sort_key(value) for value in unique_values])
sorted_unique_values = unique_values[sorted_indices]
sorted_indices = np.argsort(sorted_indices)
print(sorted_unique_values)
print(sorted_indices)
```

Output:

```
['ip1' 'ip2' 'ip5' 'ip7' 'ip12' 'ip17' 'ip22']
[0 4 5 1 6 2 3]
```

Comment: Thank you but your `idx` does not have the same length as the original `R` list! your resulted names are correct though! my desired `idx` is `array([0, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 6])`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using numpy already, you might find it's faster to use numpy to convert the strings to integers instead of looping over the list in python.

First, let's define `R` as a `np.ndarray`:

```
>>> R=np.array(["ip1", "ip7", "ip12", "ip5", "ip2", "ip22", "ip7", "ip1", "ip17", "ip22"])
```

We can split this into a 2d array of characters like so:

```
>>> R_chars = R.view('U1').reshape((len(R), -1))

array([['i', 'p', '1', ''],
       ['i', 'p', '7', ''],
       ['i', 'p', '1', '2'],
       ['i', 'p', '5', ''],
       ['i', 'p', '2', ''],
       ['i', 'p', '2', '2'],
       ['i', 'p', '7', ''],
       ['i', 'p', '1', ''],
       ['i', 'p', '1', '7'],
       ['i', 'p', '2', '2']], dtype='<U1')
```

Then, slice out the first two characters:

```
>>> R_sliced = R_chars[:, 2:]
array([['1', ''],
       ['7', ''],
       ['1', '2'],
       ['5', ''],
       ['2', ''],
       ['2', '2'],
       ['7', ''],
       ['1', ''],
       ['1', '7'],
       ['2', '2']], dtype='<U1')
```

And combine the characters of the sliced array:

```
>>> new_dtype_size = R_sliced.shape[1] 

2

>>> new_dtype = f"U{new_dtype_size}"

'U2'

>>> R_ints = R_sliced.view(new_dtype).astype(int).squeeze()

array([ 1,  7, 12,  5,  2, 22,  7,  1, 17, 22])
```

Now that you have all the integers, you can use `np.unique` on `R_ints` to get the indices of the sorted unique elements:

```
>>> _, i, idx = np.unique(R_ints, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

array([0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 8, 5], dtype=int64)
```

And finally create `names` as `R[i]`:

```
>>> names = R[i]

array(['ip1', 'ip2', 'ip5', 'ip7', 'ip12', 'ip17', 'ip22'], dtype='<U4')
```